# Divs Keep Overlapping

Tags: css, html

I have been having trouble getting the three divs on the bottom of my page to align themselves correctly. What I want is for them to sit side by side in a row. I have tried changing the float, clear, position, display, and margin properties for the #schedule, #sponsors, and #contact but they always want to overlap each other.

Here is the jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/MMcMurry16/bpU8M/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matt McMurry Racing</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "R3.css">
</head>
<div id = "container">
    <a href = "Main.html"><div id = "main"></div></a>
    <a href = "Matt TV.html"><div id = "matt_tv"></div></a>
    <a href = "24@16.html"><div id = "twentyfour"></div></a>
    <a href = "Schedule.html"><div id = "schedule" class = "bottom"></div></a>
    <a href = "Sponsors.html"><div id = "sponsors" class = "bottom"></div></a>
    <a href = "Contact.html"><div id = "contact" class = "bottom"></div></a>
</div>  
</html>


    #container{
margin: auto;
width: 650px;
height: 650px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#main{
width: 415.8px;
height: 415.8px;
clear: left;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#matt_tv{
width: 201px;
height: 201px;
clear: right;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#twentyfour{
width: 201px;
height: 201px;
clear: right;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#schedule{
width: 201px;
height: 201px;
clear: right;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
#sponsors{
width: 201px;
height: 201px;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
position: relative;
}
#contact{
width: 201px;
height: 201px;
float: left;
clear: left;
border: 1px solid #AF0000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
.bottom{
display: table-row;
margin-bottom: -305px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have 6 divs (and - HTML5 aside - it's best to wrap the `a` tags inside the `div`s) But for aligning any number of elements, CSS Flexbox is your friend here - `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;` on a new the parent container will distribute the three bottom contained `div` or `a` tags equally over the available space. [Cheatsheet here](https://daveeveritt.github.io/flexbox-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 2):

Well you are using invalid HTML for one, divs don't go inside anchor tags. Put the div around the anchor tag.

Comment: This is ok, but it should be a comment since it's not a proper/complete/valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't just a problem with overlapping, `clear` and `float` are the key here.

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

[More info here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

You can achieve what you want with this simple changes:

```
#sponsors {
    float: left; /* add floating */
    }   
#schedule {
    /*clear: right; remove clearing */
    }   
#contact {
    /*clear: left; remove clearing */
    }
.bottom {
    /*margin-bottom: -305px; you wont gonna need this anymore*/
    }
```

[Live Demo!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/bpU8M/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bpU8M/1/)**

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#main {
    width: 415.8px;
    height: 415.8px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#matt_tv {
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    clear: right;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#twentyfour {
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    clear: right;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#schedule {
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    clear: left;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#sponsors {
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#contact {
    width: 201px;
    height: 201px;
    border: 1px solid #AF0000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #696969;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;    
}
.bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -305px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the css a lot.  I set the anchors to float not the divs, and I changed some of the css to make it all match

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/bpU8M/3/)

```
<a href="Schedule.html" class="bottom"><div id = "schedule"></div></a>
<a href="Sponsors.html" class="bottom"><div id = "sponsors" class = ""></div></a>
<a href="Contact.html" class="bottom"><div id = "contact" class = ""></div></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, but I honestly don't know what an anchor is. I'm very new to programming.

Comment: No problem, an anchor is the <a.... element.  It can be used as a hyperlink or as an anchor for content.  You should read through this chart http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/default.asp.  I'm not saying memorize it, but it's just a good reference to have.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. I knew what that was, I guess I just didn't know the correct name for it.